# How to upload a .txt or .docx file in canvas using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, file-upload

I am doing a web application with canvas where users draw images and upload files into canvas. I am able to upload only images into canvas but I need the .docx or .txt files also to be uploaded.

Here is the code for uploading images

Code in .aspx page

```
 <div style="text-align:center;">
        <p>
            <input id="fileUploadImg" type="file"   />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="button" id="btnOKOpen" value="OK" onclick="UpdateCanvas(); return false;" />
            <input type="button" id="btnCancelOpen" value="Cancel" />
        </p>
    </div>
```

On clicking button the below function updatecanvas() is called.

Code in .js file

```
function UpdateCanvas() {
var file_UploadImg = document.getElementById("fileUploadImg");
var fileExtension = "";
```

Have limited the type of files the user can upload.Though I have specified .docx or .txt in "else if" the condition isn't validated.I am able to upload .png , .jpg alone but not any other extensions

```
if (fileExtension == "jpg") {
    return true;
}
else if(fileExtension == "txt")
{
    return true;
}
else if (fileExtension == "doc") {
    return true;
}
else if (fileExtension == "docx") {
    return true;
}
else if (fileExtension == "ppt") {
    return true;
}
else if (fileExtension == "pptx") {
    return true;
}
else if (fileExtension == "xml") {
    return true;
}
else if (fileExtension == "png") {
    return true;
}

 else {
    alert("You must select a GIF file for upload");
    return false;
     }
    LoadImageIntoCanvas(URL.createObjectURL(file_UploadImg.files[0]));
 }

function LoadImageIntoCanvas(bgImageUrl) {

var image_View = document.getElementById("imageView");
var ctx = image_View.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();

img.onload = function () {
    image_View.width = img.width;

    image_View.height = img.height;
    WIDTH = img.width;
    HEIGHT = img.height;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, image_View.width, image_View.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 1, 1, img.width, img.height);
}
img.src = bgImageUrl;
}
```

Is there any other way to upload files of such type?I am new to canvas.If there is any,Please help me !! Thanks in advance !!

Comment: WTH do you mean by "*draw and upload files into canvas*"? A file cannot be drawn, and a canvas is not a server.

Comment: I myself knew a file cannot be drawn.Its a well known thing that only images can be drawn. Its understood from the question that I need the images to be drawn and files to be uploaded.. and for your sake I have edited the question. @Bergi

Comment: So, to get this straight, in principle the question has nothing to do with `canvas`, but with uploading files via AJAX?

Comment: I need the uploaded files to be displayed in canvas.I am able to display my image files but not .docx file format and so the problem !! @Boldewyn

Comment: How would a rendered .docx file in `canvas` look like? How would the browser know what to show? (If you want to show a thumbnail/preview, you will need a server-side component, that renders that _after_ the upload.) There is only one non-image format, that I know to be reliably presented in `canvas`: PDf via Mozilla's pdf.js (which you need to include first).

Comment: That's exactly what I want!! I need the file to be opened or previewed in canvas .Is there any other way ? @Boldewyn

Comment: Look at [OwnCloud](http://owncloud.org): They do previews like that for text and Word docs (although I don't know, if they use `canvas` for all the other things apart from PDF). But when you look at their source, you'll most likely find, that this is a non-trivial feature. Maybe you can incorporate OwnCloud itself in your product?